# Python Query properties of dict by value

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the count of properties in a dict where poi == true. I've included a C# example for reference, followed by my python code.

What's the correct way of doing this in Python?

C#:

```
enron_data.where(x => x.poi == true).count()
```

In Python:

```
i = 0
for key,value in enron_data.items():
    if value["poi"]:
        i = i + 1
print i
```

enron_data Sample:

```
{'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 1061827, 'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN', 'bonus': 600000, 'restricted_stock': 585062, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 585062, 'expenses': 94299, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 29, 'other': 1740, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 1, 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'email_address': 'mark.metts@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 38}}
```

Comment: Could you include sample data in enron_data

Comment: I've updated my question with an example.  I was hoping for a one liner, the code I have works, it's just tedious.

Comment: You should probably reword your question to not use the word "properties" since that word has a specific meaning in Python. Dictionaries have keys (what you lookup by) and values (what you get back).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this assuming that the `poi` is always `True` or `False`.

```
sum(int(v['poi']) for v in enron_data.values())
```

`enron_data.values()` gives you an iterator that will return values of the dictionary. We're not interested in the keys. For each one, we get the value of the `'poi'` key. That's what

```
[v['poi'] for v in enron_data.values()]
```

will give you. Assuming that `v['poi']` is always `True` or `False`, I convert it to an integer using `int()`. `int(True)` is `1` and `int(False)` is `0`. So, if I run this, I will get a list of `1`s and `0`s. Then I `sum` the entire list to get the count of `1`s (i.e. `True`s) using the `sum` builtin. I drop the `[` and `]` because I'm just going to iterate over the list and not index it or anything.

Here's another alternative that occurred to me.

```
sum(1 for v in enron_data.values() if v['poi'] is True)
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Can you break down whats going on here? The syntax is a little unfamiliar.

Comment: Why so @AmiTavory? I thought the if else was better. :)

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim That's funny. Glad your answer is the accepted one, though, personally.

Comment: @JohnnyGrimes. I've added an explanation and an alternative which I like better.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a dictionary where each value indeed has a `poi` key (which your question implies):

```
enron_data = {'foo': {'poi': True}, 'bar': {'poi': False}}
```

Then this will sum the number of `True` entries:

```
sum(1 if e['poi'] else 0 for e in enron_data.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `iter_items()` function like so:

```
i = 0
for key,value in enron_data.iter_items():
    if value["poi"]:
        i = i + 1
print i
```

OR

```
i = 0
for key,value in enron_data.iter_items():
    i += int(value["poi"])
print i
```

Comment: Hi, I try your method but it return : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter_items' （my python version is 2.7.12）

Comment: @WeiYuangHsu I am afraid you are using python 3 then. Try `enron_data.items()` instead.

Comment: Hi, i'm sure it's 2.7.12 : P
But items() do work on this case.
Thx!

Comment: @WeiYuangHsu Your welcome. If you liked my answer, please smash that upvote!

Answer (score -1):

it's not right, since when never value["poi"] has a value that not false, i will increment by 1, so you should do:

```
i = 0
for key,value in enron_data.iter_items():
    if value["poi"] == True:
        i = i + 1
print i
```

Comment: Hi, I try your method but it return : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter_items' （my python version is 2.7.12）